# Mock Object returning NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception, mocking

I have this mock:

```
@Mock
ObjectMetadata metaMock;
```

I then use it in a test with the following line of code:

```
when(client.getObjectMetadata(bucket, key)).thenReturn(metaMock);
```

My test returns a NullPointerException at this line in my method under test:

```
ObjectMetadata meta = client.getObjectMetadata(bucket, key);
```

As best as I can tell this should work. Am I doing anything wrong here? the only thing I can think is that metaMock may need to have something assigned to it. Is this the case?

Comment: You need to show us more of the code, but it looks like the client has not been initialized.

Comment: I don't think the standard NPE answer suffices here. An answer which is specific to this question would address how to initialise a `@Mock` object. For example: run the test with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` or initialise all mocked class members in a `@Before` method like so: `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`.

Comment: can you show more code. from the above code mocking is redundant